# How can I ensure all teletype/monospaced text is in a certain color?

Tags: color, typewriter

I'm trying to include some monospaced text, and I'd like it to be in a different color than the normal text.  There will be several (read: hundreds) of instances of monospaced text, and I want it all to be in a certain color.  I'm relatively new to LaTeX (only started using it in the last 8 months or so), so I can't offer much in the way of research.

I've imported the `color` package, so far.  I'm looking for all instances of `\texttt` and `\verb` to be in a certain color, without having to type `\color` in front of all of them.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could redefine `\texttt` to take an optional argument that allows you to switch colour if necessary, and if not, stick to some default colour.

In the minimal example below, `\texttt[<color>]{<stuff>}` has been redefined to take an optional `<color>` (default is `black`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\let\oldtexttt\texttt% Store \texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[2][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\ttfamily #2}}% \texttt[<color>]{<stuff>}
\begin{document}
Here is some \texttt{monospaced} text that has 
\texttt[blue]{a different colour}. You can even use 
\texttt[green!30!red]{colour mixtures}.
\end{document}
```

The use of [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) allows you to mix/blend colours as well rather than sticking to some fixed colour model.

The command `\let\oldtexttt\texttt` "stores" `\texttt` in `\oldtexttt` if you want to use it for something else. It's wasn't necessary for my example, but may have an impact in your larger document.

Answer (score 12):

You can redefine the `\texttt` and `\verb` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{ttcolor}{RGB}{255,110,120}

% redefinition of \texttt
\let\Oldtexttt\texttt
\renewcommand\texttt[1]{{\ttfamily\color{ttcolor}#1}}

% redefinition of \verb
\makeatletter
\def\verb{\relax\ifmmode\hbox\else\leavevmode\null\fi
  \bgroup\color{ttcolor}
    \verb@eol@error \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
    \verbatim@font\@noligs
    \@ifstar\@sverb\@verb}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\texttt{test monospaced} and some normal font

\verb!test verbatim! and some normal font

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not acting on `\verbatim@font`, so that also the `verbatim` environment would be affected?

Answer (score 7):

If you use `xelatex` or `lualatex` then the [`fontspec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package has commands that allow you to specify the *colour* of a font.  As an example:

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setmainfont{texgyrebonum-regular.otf}
\setmonofont[Colour=blue]{Inconsolata}
\newfontface\redverbfont[Colour=red]{Inconsolata}

\newcommand\redtt[1]{{\redverbfont #1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\redverb{\begingroup\let\verbatim@font=\redverbfont\let\verb@egroup=\colverb@egroup\verb} %}
\def\colverb@egroup{\global\let\verb@balance@group\@empty\egroup\endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

A surprisingly useful feature of the \texttt{fontspec} package is that it allows one to specify a colour for a font.
So by using it with the \verb+\setmonofont+ command, all monospaced text can be coloured.

It's even possible to define other \redtt{coloured monospace} using the \redverb+\newfontface+ command.
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: coloured monospace font]

Note that the only complicated code is hacking the `\verb` command so that `\redverb` is a special "do the same as `\verb` but make the font red instead.".